# How to check if it's docker or host machine inside bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, docker

I am writing a shell script for docker containers.
I want to check before running my script whether it's docker container or host machine.

something like this:

```
if $MACHINE=docker; then
   echo proceed
elif $MACHINE=host; then
   echo 'it's not container'
   exit
fi
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check if any of the control groups belong to docker:

```
if grep -q docker /proc/1/cgroup; then 
   echo inside docker 
else
   echo on host
   exit
fi
```

Comment: Interesting, entry `0` says `0::/init.scope` on my host machine and `0::/system.slice/containerd.service` on the guest machine. I think that it would be cleaner to check for `containerd.service`. Either way, it was useful to learn about this trick.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `virt-what`, it can identify Docker now. You can install it either using `apt install virt-what` or `yum install virt-what`, on Debian and derivatives or Red Hat and derivatives respectively. If it returns code 0, no error, it's a physical machine or unidentified virtual machine type. Docker returns `docker`.

[virt-what detected platforms](https://people.redhat.com/%7Erjones/virt-what/virt-what.txt)

Comment: most of the dockers I use are not yum/apt. But ```virt-what``` is a great. Thanks @Krackout

Comment: It's a shell script actually, it can be downloaded and executed. I referred `apt` & `yum` for convinience.

Comment: from ```http://git.annexia.org/?p=virt-what.git;a=tree``` virt-what is not shell script. It's a C program. @Krackout

Comment: @AkhilJalagam  Out of curiosity, I looked a bit for it: From virt-what man page: «virt-what is a shell script which can be used to detect if the program is running in a virtual machine». You can also check the source tarballs in its home page, http://people.redhat.com/~rjones/virt-what. I also checked an installed one on Debian, the executable is indeed a shell script but there's an elf binary helper also (at least in the debian package). In the link you send, virt-what.in is the executable shell script. But the helper in C is also there. Can't tell for sure, I relied on man page.

Comment: Oh! yes. there is a shell script. I ignored it by seeing ```.in``` in the extension. Thanks @Krackout

Comment: inside the vmware-host or docker it just returns `vmware` is it normal?

Comment: @alper normally VMware is run on bare metal. So if you really run `virt-what` on a VMware ESXi server or Workstation, it should return 0. Probably you have a Linux VM under VMware, ESXi or Workstation; on that VM you run docker. `virt-what` on the VM will return `vmware`. If you run `virt-what` inside a docker instance, inside Linux VM, you should get `docker`.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn’t work with cgroup 2.0, and it doesn’t work inside Docker Desktop on Mac.

```
root@8a1d175a0b6c:/# cat /proc/self/cgroup

0::/
```

The presence of a `/.dockerenv` file on the root filesystem in Linux is probably a more reliable way to know that you’re running inside a Docker container, but that doesn’t give you your container ID; it’s just an empty file.

There needs to be a less fragile way to

1. detect when you’re running in a container, and
2. get your own container ID.

The Docker team really dropped the ball on this. At a minimum, they should have put the container ID inside `/.dockerenv`.